# Script to create partition and add it to fstab using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash script which create partition

```
dmesg | grep SCSI

echo "Partition number. ex 1..2..3"
read partnumber

echo "Provide folder name for mounting"
read datadrivefolder

(
echo o
echo n
echo p
echo $partnumber
echo
echo
echo w
) | sudo fdisk /dev/sdc

sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc$partnumber
sudo mkdir /$datadrivefolder
sudo mount /dev/sdc$partnumber /$datadrivefolder
```

Now I want to add automatically to fstab but need to get UUID using `sudo -i blkid` and add it to fstab.

1. How to extract UUID
2. How to append to end of line of fstab automatically with data information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

extract UUID

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdc$partnumber)"
```

append to end of line of fstab automatically with data information

```
echo "/dev/sdc$partnumber    /$datadrivefolder    ext4    defaults    0    1" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

OR

```
echo "UUID="$OUTPUT"    /$datadrivefolder    ext4    defaults    0    1" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```